# How to remove image background using Canny

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

So I got this image with a busy background and I want to remove the device inside it:

[image]

I wrote a basic Canny script to get a highlight of the device:

```
import cv2

# Read the original image
img = cv2.imread('antigen.png')

# Convert to graycsale
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Blur the image for better edge detection
img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (3,3), 0)

# Canny Edge Detection
edges = cv2.Canny(image=img_blur, threshold1=100, threshold2=200) # Canny Edge Detection

# Display Canny Edge Detection Image
cv2.imshow('Canny Edge Detection', edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

How can I use the outline from the canny image to basically cut out the device from the original pic from its background?

Comment: You can detect contours and find the biggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cv2.matchTemplate to perform template matching by finding the best matched ROI.
[image: The template i used]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Resizes a image and maintains aspect ratio
def maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(image, width=None, height=None, inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
    # Grab the image size and initialize dimensions
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    # Return original image if no need to resize
    if width is None and height is None:
        return image

    # We are resizing height if width is none
    if width is None:
        # Calculate the ratio of the height and construct the dimensions
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)
    # We are resizing width if height is none
    else:
        # Calculate the ratio of the 0idth and construct the dimensions
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    # Return the resized image
    return cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=inter)

# Load template, convert to grayscale, perform canny edge detection
template = cv2.imread('template.jpg')
template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)
(tH, tW) = template.shape[:2]
cv2.imshow("template", template)

# Load original image, convert to grayscale
original_image = cv2.imread('1AWH8.jpg')
(img_height, img_width)=original_image.shape[:2]
final = original_image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
found = None

# Dynamically rescale image for better template matching
for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)[::-1]:

    # Resize image to scale and keep track of ratio
    resized = maintain_aspect_ratio_resize(gray, width=int(gray.shape[1] * scale))
    r = gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

    # Stop if template image size is larger than resized image
    if resized.shape[0] < tH or resized.shape[1] < tW:
        break

    # Detect edges in resized image and apply template matching
    canny = cv2.Canny(resized, 50, 200)
    detected = cv2.matchTemplate(canny, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
    (_, max_val, _, max_loc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(detected)

    # Higher correlation means better match
    if found is None or max_val > found[0]:
        found = (max_val, max_loc, r)

# Compute coordinates of bounding box
(_, max_loc, r) = found
(start_x, start_y) = (int(max_loc[0] * r), int(max_loc[1] * r))
(end_x, end_y) = (int((max_loc[0] + tW) * r), int((max_loc[1] + tH) * r))

# Draw bounding box on ROI to remove
cv2.rectangle(original_image, (start_x, start_y), (end_x, end_y), (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.imshow('detected', original_image)
# Erase unwanted ROI (Fill ROI with white)
cv2.rectangle(final, (start_x, start_y), (end_x, end_y), (255,255,255), -1)
cv2.imwrite('final.jpg', final)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: The final image i got]

Comment: Wait. What is `template.jpg`? Where are you getting that from?

Comment: Also, this doesn't work for images of the device with different orientation.

Comment: template image is the image of the object you are interested in to remove. template matching is not scalable for different orientation. You can refer to feature detection methods using opencv. [link](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d51/group__features2d__main.html)